# Connecting form in Unbounce landing page to Pardot form handler

Tags: integration, pardot

I need to link a form placed on a landing page created in Unbounce with a Pardot form handler. Does anybody know if there is a direct integration between Pardot and Unbounce?

Answer (score 0):

From my previous Pardot implementations, some of them involved Unbounce. One thing you can try is using Unbounce webhooks to send info from forms to Pardot:

> Unbounce will fire a notification to a URL of your choice everytime the form is submitted. We'll include all of the values that were submitted in the form, as well as some details about what page and variant the lead was captured on.

The above is from the Unbounce page: [Integrating your service with unbounce](https://documentation.unbounce.com/hc/en-us/articles/203708344-Integrating-Your-Service-with-Unbounce)

What that basically does is send the information your subscribers fill in the Unbounce form to an URL of your choice (the Pardot form handler).